# How to detect and cast string back into right type in Python

Tags: python, string, casting

In my python server code, I am getting all arguments as strings. I am unaware of the original type of the argument.

For example,
if the actual value is integer 10, the argument received is string value '10'
if the actual value is string "apple". The argument received is unchanged string 'apple'
if the actual value is float 10.0 , the argument received is string value '10.0'

What is the best way to detect the right type of the argument and cast them back to 'int'  in the first example, 'string' in the second example, 'float' in the third example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you want to fix the client code so it doesn't throw away type information in the first place. Or, if you can't do that, you at least want to know what the rule is for how these strings are generated, so you can work out how to reverse the rule.

---

But if neither of those is possible, and you need to guess, one possibility is something like this:

```
def parseval(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return s
```

This will treat anything that could be a valid `int` as an `int`, anything that can't be a valid `int` but could be a valid `float` as a `float`, and anything else as a `str`.

---

In the special case where the output comes from just calling `repr` or `str` in Python, you may want this:

```
import ast
def parseval(s):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

This will convert any Python literal, or any collection display made up of literals and other collection displays made up of etc. recursively, to the original value, but leave anything else as itself. (If you know the client is using `repr` rather than `str`, you should leave off the `try`/`except`. But if it's using `str`, this works, because it relies on the fact that, for every kind of literal but strings, the `str` is interpretable as a `repr`.)

---

However, note that this makes it impossible to, e.g., send the string `"10"` to your server.